# Vue.js element loose their css in prod

Tags: vue.js, build

I come to you because I have not found anything answering my questions.
I am currently doing a project in vue.js and when putting in production some elements lose their css. If someone has already had the same problem and could help me :)
(sorry for my bad english)

Some pictures so you can see what I'm talking about
[This is my div in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu8I4.png)

[And this one in prod...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODrL3.png)

Comment: Do you have any kind of error anywhere ? What is your stack and what do you use for your styling, any framework or plain CSS ?

Comment: I don't have any errors. I only use vue, some vuetify and scss. I'm new in this

Comment: Alright, can you share some of your code/configuration ?

Comment: I found a solution. I had to pass some styles directly into "style" tags in my div. It works for me. thanks for your time